# Conversion of matrix to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have this code:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,2,2), b=c(2,2,2,2,1), c=c(3,3,3,3,4), d=c(6,6,6,6,7))

tblFun <- function(x){
  tbl <- table(x)
  res <- cbind(tbl,round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2))
  colnames(res) <- c('Count','Percentage')
  res
}
```

If I ran:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(df,tblFun))
```

I receive:

```
  Count Percentage
1     1         20
2     4         80
1     1         20
2     4         80
3     4         80
4     1         20
6     4         80
7     1         20
```

But if I run:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(df,tblFun)))
```

I receive:

```
     Count Percentage
X1       1         20
X2       4         80
X1.1     1         20
X2.1     4         80
X3       4         80
X4       1         20
X6       4         80
X7       1         20
```

I want to modify code so that it makes data frame with first column like **output in console** (not the actual content of matrix that we see with `View()`! ) of running `do.call(rbind,lapply(df,tblFun))`. How this can be done?

Comment: Convert it to `tibble` `as_tibble(do.call(rbind, lapply(df, tblFun)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to duplicate row names (with `data.frame` - duplicate row names are not allowed), which gets modified with `make.unique`.   According to `?data.frame`

> check.rows- TRUE then the rows are checked for consistency of length and names.

```
out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(df,tblFun))
row.names(out) <- NULL
as.data.frame(out)
# Count Percentage
#1     1         20
#2     4         80
#3     1         20
#4     4         80
#5     4         80
#6     1         20
#7     4         80
#8     1         20
```

If we really need the rownames as index, create that as a column, before assigning the `row.names` to `NULL`

```
out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(df,tblFun))
out <- cbind(index = as.numeric(row.names(out)), out)
row.names(out) <- NULL
as.data.frame(out)
#. index Count Percentage
31     1     1         20
#2     2     4         80
#3     1     1         20
#4     2     4         80
#5     3     4         80
#6     4     1         20
#7     6     4         80
#8     7     1         20
```

Comment: Your code deletes the information that is outputted in console from the matrix (it does not shows the index of the row, but shows variable value that is tested).

Comment: @vasili111. You may need to create a column of index, otherwise duplicate row name are not permitted

Comment: There is also `rbind.data.frame`. In the first code example it will save one code line: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(df, tblFun))`.